# Two models accept nested attributes for each other, generate stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm wondering if I'm only the one with this issue. To pinpoint it, I have created two very basic models.

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :role, :inverse_of => :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :role
end

# role.rb
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :role
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

In the rails console, attempting to update a simple attribute of the Role class fails *if the User model has been loaded*.

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.2)
1.9.3-p194 :001 > Role.first.update_attribute(:role_type, 72)
 => true 
1.9.3-p194 :002 > Role.first.tap {|r| r.user}.update_attribute(:role_type, 72)
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    from /Users/enelson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80
Maybe IRB bug!
```

If I remove *either one* of the accepts_nested_attributes directives, this problem goes away. I guess the easy answer here is "well then, why don't you get rid of one of them?" The problem is that would involve rewriting a lot of existing pages in an application, and if there's a different fix or workaround, I'd like to hear about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Design-wise, it's not correct composition that Role "has a" User. It may be better to correct the design at this stage, rather than leave it.

Both relationships are also defined as "inverse of" the other;  that might also possibly be contributing to the infinite recursion.

Comment: Well, sure enough, removing both `inverse_of` properties fixed the error. I was under the impression that specifying inverses was generally "good practice" to cut down on re-loading models, but perhaps it interacts negatively with `accepts_nested_attributes`?

Comment: Normally it would be nice to have the bi-directional relationship modelled correctly. What's the better solution long-term?

Comment: User & Role are made-up models I created for this debugging project -- in our actual app, it's essentially one parent model and lots of child models. For now, taking out the `inverse_of` is an easy fix. In the future, this glitch might be an incentive for a UX change in our app (breaking up that page into several small forms that submit to each individual model rather than one big form that updates all the models).

Comment: Where necessary, you could instead create a 'View' class -- which does not exist in the database, but composites the data you need by loading various persistent objects to be presented & edited in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, found this: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7809 and then this pull request https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7824.
Added it as monkeypatch to project, hope it won't introduce any nasty bugs.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), you should remove `accetps_nested_attributes_for` from the `Role` model, and keep both of the `inverse_of`.